# Getting compilation error for header file execinfo.h

Tags: linux, compilation

Getting compilation error on linux build environment when trying to include this header file in my codebase. Error getting -

```
enter code here /execinfo.h:28: error: parse error before "__nonnull"
```

/execinfo.h:34: error: parse error before "__nonnull"
/execinfo.h:40: error: parse error before "__nonnull"

System details = Linux distribution- CentOS release 5.4 (Final) glibc- ldd (GNU libc) 2.5 gcc -gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide lines 28, 34 and 40 of execinfo.h

Comment: 28 extern int backtrace (void **__array, int __size) __nonnull ((1));
 29
 30
 31 /* Return names of functions from the backtrace list in ARRAY in a newly
 32    malloc()ed memory block.  */
 33 extern char **backtrace_symbols (void *__const *__array, int __size)
 34      __THROW __nonnull ((1));
 35
 36
 37 /* This function is similar to backtrace_symbols() but it writes the result
 38    immediately to a file.  */
 39 extern void backtrace_symbols_fd (void *__const *__array, int __size, int __fd)
 40      __THROW __nonnull ((1));

Comment: Which Linux distribution do you use and what are the gcc and glibc versions?

Comment: Linux distribution- CentOS release 5.4 (Final) glibc- ldd (GNU libc) 2.5 gcc -gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)

Comment: Please [edit] your original question and add all the additional info in it. Do you include the execinfo.h header directly or is it included through a different header? Can you provide the full error output? What compiler flags do you use?

Comment: It could be you have an syntax error somewhere else (like unbalanced `{` `}`) and your compiler gets confused. [__nonnull](https://github.com/walac/glibc/blob/master/misc/sys/cdefs.h#L286) should be defined in glibc. Could you post full error message?

Comment: I am trying to compile in my code base which create 32 bit binaries on 64 bit machine so I included the header file at the proper place inside my codebase. Full error o/p is this only-/execinfo.h:28: error: parse error before "__nonnull"
/execinfo.h:34: error: parse error before "__nonnull"
/execinfo.h:40: error: parse error before "__nonnull"
 Compiler flags related to different modules created inside our codebase CFLAGS += -I. -I../util -I../mgmt_common -I../mwm  -I../eprom .

Comment: @Kriti, Try including `sys/cdefs.h` header just before including `execinfo.h`.

Comment: @VasilVelichkov Tried still getting same error.

Comment: @Kriti, Do you get the same error if you build it in 64bit mode? Do you get the same error when you include this header in a simple program - like only the include and a main function that does nothing? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @VasilVelichkov No for 64 bit when I am creating a simple program then I am not getting this error.

Comment: @Kriti, do you get an error when you compile the simple program for 32 bit?

Comment: @VasilVelichkov yes

Comment: @Kriti, Can you provide this simple program, together with the full command you are using to build it and the full build output?

Comment: It's of huge size I can't share it here. After doing the changes related to  backtrace and importing execinfo.h and when doing make getting error that I have mentioned above.

Comment: @Kiri, I was asking about sharing the simple program, it should be 5 lines and together with the build command and full output it should not be that large.

Comment: But as I want to do stacktrace in my codebase which is of big size. so should I share the particular lines related to stacktrace present in my codebase?